# How to use np.where() to create a new array of specific rows?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, extract, where-clause

I have an array (msaarr) of 1700 values, ranging from approximately 0 to 150. I know that 894 of these values should be less than 2, and I wish to create a new array containing only these values.

So far, I have attempted this code:

```
Combined = np.zeros(shape=(894,8))

for i in range(len(Spitzer)):         #len(Spitzer) = 1700
    index = np.where(msaarr <= 2)
    Combined[:,0] = msaarr[index]
```

The reason there are eight columns is because I have more data associated with each value in msaarr that I also want to display. msaarr was created using several lines of code, which is why I haven't mentioned them here, but it is an array with shape (1700,1) with type float64.

The problem I'm having is that if I print msaarr[index], then I get an array of shape (893,), but when I attempt to assign this as my zeroth column, I get the error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1699) into shape (894)
```

I also attempted

```
Combined[:,0] = np.extract(msaarr <= 2, msaarr)
```

Which gave the same error.

I thought at first this might just be some confusion with Python's zero-indexing, so I tried changing the shape to 893, and also tried to assign to a different column Combined[:,1], but I have the same error every time.

Alternatively, when I try:

```
Combined[:,1][i] = msaarr[index][i]
```

I get the error:

```
IndexError: index 894 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 894
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

A friend pointed out that I might not be calling index correctly because it is a tuple, and so his suggestion was this:

```
index = np.where(msaarr < 2)
Combined[:,0] = msaarr[index[0][:]]
```

But I am still getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (893,1) into shape (893)
```

How can my shape be (893) and not (893, 1)?

Also, I did check, and len(index[0][:]) = 893, and len(msaarr[index[0][:]]) = 893.

The full code as of last attempts is:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import ascii
from astropy.io import fits

targets = fits.getdata('/Users/vcolt/Dropbox/ATLAS source matches/OzDES.fits')
Spitzer = ascii.read(r'/Users/vcolt/Desktop/Catalogue/cdfs_spitzer.csv', header_start=0, data_start=1)

## Find minimum separations, indexed.
RADiffArr = np.zeros(shape=(len(Spitzer),1))
DecDiffArr = np.zeros(shape=(len(Spitzer),1))
msaarr = np.zeros(shape=(len(Spitzer),1))
Combined= np.zeros(shape=(893,8))

for i in range(len(Spitzer)):
    x = Spitzer["RA_IR"][i]
    y = Spitzer["DEC_IR"][i]
    sep = abs(np.sqrt(((x - targets["RA"])*np.cos(np.array(y)))**2 + (y - targets["DEC"])**2))
    minsep = np.nanmin(sep)
    minseparc = minsep*3600
    msaarr[i] = minseparc
    min_positions = [j for j, p in enumerate(sep) if p == minsep]
    x2 = targets["RA"][min_positions][0]
    RADiff = x*3600 - x2*3600
    RADiffArr[i] = RADiff
    y2 = targets["DEC"][min_positions][0]
    DecDiff = y*3600 - y2*3600
    DecDiffArr[i] = DecDiff

index = np.where(msaarr < 2)
print msaarr[index].shape
Combined[:,0] = msaarr[index[0][:]]
```

I get the same error whether index = np.where(msaarr < 2) is in or out of the loop.

Comment: Are you able to include your full code in your post?  `index = np.where(msaarr <= 2)` seems questionable...

Comment: An observation: You have said that there will be 894 values less than 2 but in the code you are using less than and equal to 2.

Comment: "if I print msaarr[index], then I get an array of shape (893,)" - what, did you count the elements? How did you get a shape of `(893,)`? Can you put `print msaarr[index].shape` before the problematic assignment and post the results, including both `print` output and stack trace?

Comment: @user2357112 I assigned `test = msaarr[index]`, `print test`, then just checked what the size was in variable explorer. I'm afraid I don't know what a stack trace is, but when I do `print msaarr[index].shape` I get the output `(893,)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using `numpy.take` in combination with `numpy.where`.

```
inds = np.where(msaarr <= 2)
new_msaarr = np.take(msaarr, inds)
```

If it is a multi-dimensional array, you can also add the `axis` keyword to take slices along that axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think loop is not at the right place. `np.where()` will return an array of index of elements which matches the condition you have specified.

This should suffice

```
Index = np.where(msaarr <= 2)
```

Since index is an array. You need to loop over this index and fill the values in combined[:0]

Also I want to point out one thing. You have said that there will be 894 values less than 2 but in the code you are using less than and equal to 2.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow. Are you saying to move `index = np.where(msaarr <= 2)` out of the loop? Also, to loop over the index to fill the values in Combined, do you mean something like `for i in index Combined[:,0] = msaarr`? 
I put the <= in just in case there was somehow something exactly equal to two that I missed, but I don't think it should matter much either way, that can be changed to just <, but it hasn't stopped the errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where(condition)` will return a tuple of arrays containing the indexes of elements that verify your condition.
To get an array of the elements verifying your condition use:

```
new_array = msaarr[msaarr <= 2]
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 4))
>>> x
array([[1, 6, 8, 4],
       [0, 6, 6, 5],
       [9, 6, 4, 4],
       [9, 6, 8, 6]])
>>> x[x>2]
array([6, 8, 4, 6, 6, 5, 9, 6, 4, 4, 9, 6, 8, 6])
```